# Is there any python program where i can replace two string from two list

Tags: python

I have two lists

```
a= ['how to get  my bill', 'Where can I locate my  GPA', 'where do I find  GPA']
b= ['GPA', 'G.P.A', 'bill']
```

I  want to replace the value of `b` from `a`.

The output should be:

```
['how to get  my GPA', 'How to get my G.P.A','Where can I locate my  G.P.A', 'Where can I locate my  bill', 'where do I find  bill', 'where do I find  G.P.A']
```

I have tried this code, where I have spiltted each word and converted it into a string

```
w = (a['Utterances'])
y = (str(w)[1:-1])
q = [word.strip(string.punctuation) for word in y.split()]
```

Comment: can i use the same code with excel file. i will take the data from the column instead of a and b

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach relying on (hopefully) clearer operations:

```
a= ['how to get  my bill', 'Where can I locate my  GPA', 'where do I find  GPA']
b= ['GPA', 'G.P.A', 'bill']

results = []
for phrase in a:
    for word in phrase.split():
        if word in b:
            results += [phrase.replace(word, other) for other in b if other != word]

print(results)
```

Which also gives:

```
['how to get  my GPA', 'how to get  my G.P.A', 'Where can I locate my  G.P.A', 'Where can I locate my  bill', 'where do I find  G.P.A', 'where do I find  bill']
```

Comment: how can i do the same thing if a = [['how to get  my bill'], ['Where can I locate my  student records'], ['Where can I locate my  GPA'], ['how do I find  my bill'], ['How do I find my  student records'], ['where can I find  my bill'], ['where can I locate  my bill'], ['where do I find  GPA'], ['I want my  student records'], ['Where do I find my  academic standing'], ['Where do I find my  student records'], ['where do I I find my  GPA']]
b = [["'GPA', 'G P A', 'G.P.A'"], ["'academic standing'"], ["'my bill', 'bill'"], ["'student records'"], ["'time sheet', 'timesheet'"]]

Comment: Is there any reason that `b` needs to be a list of lists? If so, I would just make a copy containing all elements in a single list, e.g. `c = []; for elem in b: c += elem`

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be:

```
a= ['how to get  my bill', 'Where can I locate my  GPA', 'where do I find  GPA']
b= ['GPA', 'G.P.A', 'bill']
final_lst = []
for i in a:
    lst = i.split()
    ignore_ix = b.index(lst[-1])
    new_str = [i[:i.find(lst[-1])]+j for j in b[:ignore_ix]+b[ignore_ix+1:]]
    final_lst.extend(new_str)

print(final_lst)
```

And a shorter one would be:

```
from itertools import product
a= ['how to get  my bill', 'Where can I locate my  GPA', 'where do I find  GPA']
b= ['GPA', 'G.P.A', 'bill']
result = [i.replace(i.split()[-1],j) for i,j in product(a,b) if i.split()[-1]!=j]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['how to get  my GPA', 'how to get  my G.P.A', 'Where can I locate my  G.P.A', 'Where can I locate my  bill', 'where do I find  G.P.A', 'where do I find  bill']
```

Answer (score 0):

The newlist is what you want.

```
newlist = []
for items in a:
    for values in b:
        if values not in items:
            frontpart = items.rsplit(' ', 1)[0]
            newlist.append(frontpart + " " + values)
print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

please check the below code.

```
from itertools import chain

a= ['how to get  my bill', 'Where can I locate my  GPA', 'where do I find  GPA']
b= ['GPA', 'G.P.A', 'bill']

def replace_val(sent,words):
    word_to_replace = set(sent.split()) & set(words)
    replace_with = set(words) - word_to_replace
    return {sent.replace(i,j) for i in word_to_replace for j in replace_with}


print(list(chain(*[replace_val(i,b) for i in a])))
```

It outputs the expected strings.

```
['how to get  my GPA', 'how to get  my G.P.A', 'Where can I locate my  bill', 'Where can I locate my  G.P.A', 'where do I find  bill', 'where do I find  G.P.A']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer that you are looking. Hope this will help.

```
output = set()
for replace_word in b:
    for sentence in a:
        d = sentence.replace(sentence.split()[-1], replace_word)
        output.add(d)
output = list(output - set(a))
```

**Output:**

```
['how to get  my GPA', 'Where can I locate my  G.P.A', 'Where can I locate my  bill', 'where do I find  bill', 'where do I find  G.P.A', 'how to get  my G.P.A']
```